# Hide answer bodies in careers profile

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, design

The "public" and "employer" views of the careers profile look very clean and beautifully designed.

The only deviation from that is the "top answers" section. The arbitrary formatting inside each answer body (code snippets, bullets, sometimes even images!), repeated for every answer, makes the whole list very hard to follow. I  put it to you that <strike>a recruiter</strike> heck, **anybody!** will have huge trouble understanding what this is about.

To wit, this is what my profile looks like with and without my favourite SO answers.

[image]

**The request**: please hide the answer body. Show the question titles only, in a neat list; show the full answer body on click.

As a sketch, including @phwd's suggestion:

[image]

it might even be an idea to show the question's tags in the list, because *that* may be relevant information to an employer.

Comment: I would go even further and say to remove the black vote block all together. The title links to the SE site so whoever is watching can click through if they like and see how many votes were allocated. The feature already shows the highest ranked items so placing the votes seems a bit redundant.

Comment: Friends help you move.  Real friends help you hide bodies.  The question you should be asking yourself is, *which of my friends will help me hide these answer bodies?*

Comment: did you consider doing it the other way 'round? I mean, selecting and back-editing answers text so that it looks good in Careers (that way [works for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107768/165773)). Also note, "top answers" section may be not the only one that _deviates_ the way you describe: "Writing" and "Reading" get quite long too, if done right. Once upon a time I made a [feature request to address this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103860/stack-overflow-careers-profile-all-in-one-approach-issues-etc-usability-observ "separate tabs for... Stack Exchange, Writing, Reading?")

Comment: @gnat interesting suggestion. I guess that could be a workaround if you really, really want your favourite answers in there. But in general, this really needs to be fixed on Careers' end. Especially if there's even more!

Comment: well can't tell I really like the change you suggested - the way I see it, it may really hurt the SEO of the answers I crafted into my Careers profile. Though, if there would be an editable "answer summary" - like one we have for articles and books - this probably could meet both your and my needs at once (your would fit empty summary). Side note I also find the votes-based selection you seem to use quite slippery (["trouble with popularity"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)) - but that's not my problem. :)

Comment: @gnat hmm, I haven't thought about SEO, but are you sure that would ever be relevant? Would the original answer (from where I can find you as the author) not always beat your profile in SEO? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by votes-based selection - you mean the answers in the example? They're not my top-ranking answers in votes, not by far, pretty much for the reasons in your linked article :)

Comment: @Pekka I look at it the other way 'round. I rather feel that a dozen or two properly selected excerpts concentrated in Careers profile is more SEO-friendly than bits of the same info sparsely spread over SO in hundreds (thousands in your case) of the answers. Answers to me serve an _after-SEO_ purpose: those attracted from Careers can dig into these to deeper examine my background and skills. As for the way you choose answers, really good to hear that you do it the right way, I was somewhat mislead by "top answers" mentioned. I guess you found right way to expose your rep in Careers, correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is planned as part of several changes to the profile view.  There should be something coming on this soon.

Comment: I see this is implemented now. Looks great, congrats!

Comment: @Pekka better late than never, I hope

Answer (score 20):

*[This is more supporting material, **not** an answer. But the confines of MSO do not allow adding images to comments so I have to add this as an answer.]*

A header in an embedded answer is another egregious example of original formatting clashing with the formatting of the containing Careers page. Notice how I have a header in my answer that is easily confused with the parent headings of the Careers profile. To my mind, suppressing font sizes, font colors, and horizontal rules in the embedded answer would go a long way towards eliminating the stylistic abomination (if that is not too strong term :-).

I also want to second the notion of displaying question titles only, with the answers displayable on demand. Even better, have a setup option that lets one select whether to expand answers or collapse to titles only.

[image: sample of clashing due to font sizes and colors]

Comment: Good catch! ---

Comment: WAIT WHERE I CANT SEE IT