# Stack Overflow Careers Profile: all-in-one approach issues etc (usability observations)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jobs, user-interface

One of the things I wrote down when editing and reviewing my [Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv):

- Profile Edit view -> all-in-one approach issues
  surrounding content makes it harder to focus on editing particular sections
  Would it make sense to have separate tabs for sections
  *Experience, Stack Exchange, Writing, Reading*?
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLWfh.jpg]

## update

Intent of above feature request is to make a change pretty similar to what has been done per [recent redesign of SE user page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115566/please-undelete-the-new-user-profile-discussion):
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l4z2.png]

---

### history

all other observations [originally listed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/103860/6) were extracted to separate posts as suggested in comments.

1. it would be nice for *import linkedin* to also migrate [Reading List](http://learn.linkedin.com/apps/amazon/)
   **update** extracted to separate post: [...migrate Reading List when doing "import linkedin"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103883/stack-overflow-careers-profile-migrate-reading-list-when-doing-import-linkedin)
2. Profile Edit/Public/Employer views -> Stack Exchange -> Top answers
   **update** extracted to separate post: [...add "less" button in Top answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103884/stack-overflow-careers-profile-add-less-button-in-top-answers)
3. Profile Public/Employer views -> *display more/fewer* inconsistency
   **update** extracted to separate post: [..."display more/fewer" inconsistency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103885/stack-overflow-careers-profile-display-more-fewer-inconsistency)
4. Profile Edit view -> Stack Exchange -> Top answers -> adding issues
   **update** extracted to separate post: [...Top answers -> adding issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103886/stack-overflow-careers-profile-top-answers-adding-issues)

Comment: All of these are great observations and feature-requests, but can you do us a favor and break this up into 5 posts, 1 for each point you make?  That would help track progress of these issues individually.

Comment: @NickLarsen OK will do

Comment: **update** 1-post-per-point breakup completed (I think)