# Stack Overflow Careers Profile: migrate Reading List when doing "import linkedin"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, user-interface

background: [Careers Profile: some usability observations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103860/stack-overflow-careers-profile-some-usability-observations)

- for *import linkedin* feature implementation
  it would be nice to also import [Reading List](http://learn.linkedin.com/apps/amazon/)
  manual import of about dozen books was quite cumbersome to me

Comment: LinkedIn doesn't support Reading List anymore: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41422/how-to-resurrect-ones-amazon-reading-list-data-in-shelfari