# Stack Overflow Careers Profile: add "less" button in Top answers

Tags: feature-request, jobs, user-interface

background: [Careers Profile: some usability observations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103860/stack-overflow-careers-profile-some-usability-observations)

- Profile Edit/Public/Employer views -> Stack Exchange -> Top answers
  would be nice to have "less" button that would collapse answers expanded with "more"
  [image: screen shot]