# Stack Overflow Careers Profile: "display more/fewer" inconsistency

Tags: feature-request, jobs, user-interface

background: [Careers Profile: some usability observations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103860/stack-overflow-careers-profile-some-usability-observations)

- Profile Public/Employer views -> *display more/fewer* inconsistency
  some sections have  *display more/fewer*, other don't, for example...
  ...Top answers, Writing, Reading -> Articles & Blogs lack it (bad)
  ...Experience, Reading -> Books have it (good):
  [image: screen shot - display more books]