# Folding Sections in Profiles

Tags: feature-request, jobs

The *audience* for the CVs on StackExchange Careers Site is comprised of hiring managers and the like, though for a company of more than a few dozen employees, it's common for an HR person to do some initial screening. I have found these folks to be very conservative, as a group. In particular, these people, for better or worse, are accustomed to looking at CVs having a *particular format*--a format that has remained more or less unchanged for centuries (i believe it was the ancient Babylonians who invented the CV in its current form, but at present there is no consensus among scholars).

I do *not* think the SO Career Site CV format ought to be changed to accomodate those preconceptions--i am thrilled SO is trying to change them; however, i think adding a *folding* feature would make the SO format more accessible to these administrative types (who sometimes react to an unorthodox format by tossing it and moving on to the next one in the pile). And i don't think it will compromise the awesomeness of SO Careers.

In other words, the CV ***Sections***--e.g., *Technology, Experience, Education*,..--could be initially ***folded*** in the main view then *expanded* one section at a time by clicking on the section name. If you know the [Accordion Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) in the jQuery UI Library, then you know what i'm talking about.

Or for a rough (very rough) idea:

[image]

Comment: my similar feature request suggested tabbing for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103860/stack-overflow-careers-profile-all-in-one-approach-issues-etc-usability-observa Personally I have no preference for folding or tabbing, but I definitely dislike current _all-in-one_ approach

Comment: @gnat : before i posted this Q, i would have bet anything that someone had suggested this before, but nothing came up in my search. I was actually going to suggest accordion/folding *and* tabbing *within* sections (e.g., one tab per question in the "StackExchagne* section. Hopefully this Q won't be closed in light of yours that pre-dates it.