# How does one get more hits on careers (SEO for careers?)

Tags: discussion, jobs, seo

Basically, my title says it all, is there instruction on how to optimize your profile on careers.stackoverflow.com so that you come up in more employer searches? (I mean aside from the obvious — like "fill out your profile").

Comment: Make it public, visible by employer and share it everywhere you can ?

Comment: @HoLyVieR But will that help get the search result numbers up?

Comment: Without seeing your profile, hard to say what (if anything) you're doing wrong -- why not make it public and link it here?

Comment: @agf I am more looking for SEO for careers (I do not want this to be a one-off, but a resource question), but here it is: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/callenpoole

Comment: @cwallenpoole Then maybe mention SEO specifically in the question, instead of just "optimize".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well to me SO Careers profile seems to be most SEO-friendly of all other online profiles I've been using so far (there was half dozen at least). Without knowing actual mechanics of how it works I wouldn't bet on that but anyway "it walks like a duck and it quacks like a duck" to me.

Note by the way main page of your Careers profile says **"Employer View - searchable"**.

- In other online profiles I find it troublesome to push SEO too heavily because this might actually make bad impression on human reader. At least my own feeling of reading "overloaded" resumes of candidates is quite negative.

Good thing about SO careers is that it allows to inject SEO stuff in a way that looks justified to reader - in case if one is active in answering questions or writing blog (like I noticed [you do](http://www.allen-poole.com/wordpress/)) or at least in reading books and web articles. It's not a rocket science really...

[image]

Few minor points about above.

- When displaying Stack Exchange stuff, I choose one that I want to be read by "Employer" - it doesn't matter if votes count is high or low.

  - I even once had a downvoted answer there - until it was exchanged for a *Peer Pressure* badge
- For items in Writing and in Reading - Articles sections, I heavily use an option to edit summary. Sometimes I edit Site name, too.
- For Reading - Books section, I typically fill a summary section ("What did you take away from this book?")

---

PS. My own profile is not quite optimized I'm afraid: instead of focusing on few key areas, its content is rather spread over wide range of different topics. Guess when (if:) I decide that profile may benefit of SEO boost, I'll have to cut about half of it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the "likes" are a large factor in search results — changing whether I liked a given technology changed whether or not I even placed in the search results for that tech (at all).

Comment: That is _very_ good to know.