# How to add a skill in Careers 2.0

Tags: support, jobs

I have completed my **Careers 2.0** profile. The profile appears limited.

I don't know how to proceed?  Could you please elaborate how to add more information to my **Careers 2.0 profile**?

My profile looks like:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpgwO.jpg]

In "edit" section, there was no way to add any of my skills.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the very page you used to make a screen shot, click on **my profile** to edit whatever you need:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Go6w.jpg]

---

PS. Next bit of advice...

...Now that you know how to edit Careers profile, consider looking at your SO activities from the perspective of improving it. I mean, adding appropriately chosen answers and questions might [give your profile a substantial "SEO boost"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107768/165773)

Comment: The separation between these two pages is something has been on the list for a while.  I'd say give it [6 to 8 weeks](http://www.cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at the Account details. Click on My Profile to add the skills & other details